# Create Key using two columns and do a left join SQL

Tags: sql, left-join, composite-primary-key

I have two tables I would to do a left join on.

**Order:**

| ID | CATA | Repo | Assc |

**Return:**

| ID | CATB | Addl| Sumin|

I need to create a Key using ID+CATA on Order table and ID+CATB on Return Table. And do a LEFT JOIN on Order (**Order LEFT JOIN RETURN**).
What is the easiest way to do this in one shot?

```
with table1 as
(
Select *,
CONCAT(ID, CATB) AS Key1
from Return 
)
Select*,
CONCAT(SUPERPNR, CATA) AS Key,
from
Order
as order
left join table1
on CONCAT(order.ID, order.CATA)=table1.Key1
```

Comment: why concat just join using a compound "AND" `from order o left join return r on r.cata = o.catb and o.id = r.id`  by combining fileds you eliminate the ability to use indexes.  Note: O, R are aliases to the tables.  and "ORDER" is a reserved word which likely needs to be escaped

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: CONCAT comparisons often indicates a poor design.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Don't edit a post to a different question. Ask 1 question per post. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Order ca
left join Return cb
   on (ca.id, ca.cata) = (cb.id, cb.catb);
```

Comment: If you'r not sure, you should be commenting not answering. [answer] [Help] PS All that text added nothing. Avoid social & meta commentary in posts. It is not helpful to restate code in prose. Explain why particular code answers a question.